# How to add the path of CUDA compiler in CMake under WSL?

Tags: windows, cmake, cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu on Windows (in WSL), I have CMake 3.10.1 and CUDA Toolkit 9.0. When I run

```
cmake ..
```

I got this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  No CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CUDACXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER to the full
  path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/d/Open3D-PointNet2-Semantic3D-master/tf_ops/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/mnt/d/Open3D-PointNet2-Semantic3D-master/tf_ops/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Is it possible to link CUDA and CMake in WSL and how can I add the path to CUDA?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
cmake -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-10.1 ..
```

Just change the path to where you installed

---

cuda can be installed on WSL with commands:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

`cmake` then can find the path for the build. But the executable can not be ran on the WSL because Nvidia doesn't support yet.

Comment: I used : cmake -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0" , Now here is the error:
CMake Error: The source directory "/" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @user77540 you should cd to your build directory and give the relative path to source.  The .. at the end of command I wrote

Comment: If you're on ubuntu on windows, you don't want to be referring to the windows install of CUDA.  You should have a linux install of CUDA.

Comment: Can you explain more please @RobertCrovella

Comment: In the ubuntu environment on windows, you are effectively in a linux environment.  That means you need to use CUDA tools that are designed to run in a linux environment.  If you have tools installed at `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0`, those are tools that are designed to run in a **windows** OS, not a **linux** OS.  I wouldn't be referring to that from the linux side. The answer given to you here, suggests that if you are running `cmake` in a linux environment, then the likely location for the CUDA tools you want to refer to is something like `/usr/local/cuda-10.1...`

Comment: Thank you, But in this case what should i do? switch to linux and restart all over again?

Comment: @user77540 are you aware you cannot use the GPU on your WSL?

Comment: I tried to put the directory of cuda in windows like ::/mnt/d/Open3D-PointNet2-Semantic3D-master/tf_ops/build$ cmake -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0"
CMake Error: The source directory "/mnt/d/Open3D-PointNet2-Semantic3D-master/tf_ops/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.        its the same error

Comment: @user77540 where is the .. ?

Comment: /mnt/d/Open3D-PointNet2-Semantic3D-master/tf_ops/build$ cmake -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0"..
CMake Error: The source directory "/mnt/d/Open3D-PointNet2-Semantic3D-master/tf_ops/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: @Oblivion can you explain '' the executable can not be ran on the WSL because Nvidia doesn't support yet'' i am very new in WSL